# legend style of bar plot pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, legend

I've copied an example bar plot from the manual. I had a little trouble to tweak the style of the legend. Here is what I've got.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
ylabel=\emph{Population},
xlabel=\emph{years},
enlargelimits=0.15,
% legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
% anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ybar,
bar width=9pt,
]

\addplot [black!100!white,fill=black!100!white] coordinates {
% \addplot [black!20!black,fill=black!50!white] coordinates {
(1930,50e6) (1940,33e6)
(1950,40e6) (1960,50e6) (1970,70e6)
};
\addplot [black!30!white,fill=black!30!white] coordinates {
(1930,38e6) (1940,42e6)
(1950,43e6) (1960,45e6) (1970,65e6)
};
\legend{Far,Near}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The plot look likes this

[image]

However, I want the legend to be

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `legend image code` to create whatever legend image you want.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} %<- you may want to add this
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
ylabel=\emph{Population},
xlabel=\emph{years},
enlargelimits=0.15,
% legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
% anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ybar,
bar width=9pt,
legend image code/.code={
        \draw [#1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.2cm,0.25cm); },
]

\addplot [black!100!white,fill=black!100!white] coordinates {
% \addplot [black!20!black,fill=black!50!white] coordinates {
(1930,50e6) (1940,33e6)
(1950,40e6) (1960,50e6) (1970,70e6)
};
\addplot [black!30!white,fill=black!30!white] coordinates {
(1930,38e6) (1940,42e6)
(1950,43e6) (1960,45e6) (1970,65e6)
};
\legend{Far,Near}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A possible pitfall is that you need to place `legend image code/.code={...}` *after* `ybar`, which also sets the legend style. And you may move the position of the legend such that it does not cover some of the bars.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} %<- you may want to add this
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
ylabel=\emph{Population},
xlabel=\emph{years},
enlargelimits=0.15,
legend style={at={(0.5,0.95)},
 anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ybar,
bar width=9pt,
legend image code/.code={
        \draw [#1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.2cm,0.25cm); },
]

\addplot [black!100!white,fill=black!100!white] coordinates {
% \addplot [black!20!black,fill=black!50!white] coordinates {
(1930,50e6) (1940,33e6)
(1950,40e6) (1960,50e6) (1970,70e6)
};
\addplot [black!30!white,fill=black!30!white] coordinates {
(1930,38e6) (1940,42e6)
(1950,43e6) (1960,45e6) (1970,65e6)
};
\legend{Far,Near}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]